# Cleaner Way to load multiple environment variables into shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm currently loading multiple variables into my shell (from a `.env` file) like so:

`eval $(grep '^VAR_1' .env) && eval $(grep '^VAR_2' .env) && ...`

I then use them in a script like so: `echo $VAR_1`.

Is there any way to condense this script into something like: `eval $(grep ^('VAR_1|VAR_2')) .env`? Maybe needs something other than `grep`

Comment: You can do: `eval $(grep -E '^(VAR_1|VAR_2)=' .env)`

Comment: could you update the question with a sample set of entries from your `.env` file?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just load the whole bunch? Much easier to just `. .env` and be done with it. If there are subsets that one can conditionally want to load, think about splitting them off into different files, and having the master file include those files by reference.

Comment: Otherwise you have all the pitfalls of code generation. Using `grep` makes wildly unfounded assumptions -- like assuming that there's only one assignment per line, _and_ that a variable can't have newlines in its contents (both these things are untrue; you can have one line `myvar='line1` and another line `line2'` whose contents both go into `myvar`).

Comment: ...what's worse, you can have `myvar='line1`, then `othervar=foo`, then `line3'`; those three lines, parsed correctly, _all_ go into `myvar` (no `othervar` variable should be defined at all), but there's no possible way `grep` will figure that out.

Comment: although I picked an answer which works, `. .env` also seems to work @CharlesDuffy, might just end up using that..

Comment: * if there are no comments or anything else in the file that is. A way to use `. .env` but ALSO ignore lines beginning with `#` would be ideal

Comment: `. .env` already ignores comments. By the way, if you want these variables to be exported to the environment, run `set -a` first; can be turned back off with ` set +a` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `grep` with `ERE` option to filter all the variable you want from `.env` file:

```bash
grep -E '^(VAR_1|VAR_2)=' .env
```

This pattern will find `VAR_1=` or `VAR_2=` strings at the start.

To set variable use:

```bash
declare $(grep -E '^(VAR_1|VAR_2)=' .env)

# or
eval "$(grep -E '^(VAR_1|VAR_2)=' .env)"
```

Comment: Both versions could use proper quoting and word splitting. But safer solutions depend on OP's requirements (e.g. does `.env` contain `VAR=A B C` or `VAR="A B C"`).

Comment: Note that `eval $(...anything...)` is as a rule less safe than `eval "$(...anything...)"`. If you've got `patterns='*.xml *.txt *.whatever'` in your grep output -- note the quotes making it putatively safe -- you don't want `*.txt` being replaced with a list of text files in the current directory before it reaches `eval`. Doubly if this is run in an untrusted directory with a `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks so much @CharlesDuffy, very valid point

Answer (score 3):

I would use `source` (`.`) command with process substitution:

```
. <(grep -e '^VAR_1=' -e '^VAR_2=' .env)
```

or

```
. <(grep '^VAR_[12]=' .env) # for this particular variables
```

The file `.env` must be from a trusted source, of course.
Note that the `grep` method won't work if a variable is assigned a string containing an embedded newline character.